# App has to wait for completion of API stream bevor executing further functions

Tags: json, swift, api, synchronous, completionhandler

Environment: MAC OS, Swift, XCODE 10.1
Task: I'm writing an app which reads an API stream with data. AFTER reading and parsing the json data stream, further calculation with the streamed data is done. So it's mandatory, that the complete stream is read/parsed, before continuing to calculations.
Issue: Main thread is calling a function "getLiveData" to stream the json data (Pls see code). Within this function i.e. a new timeStamp is set due to the parsed data - the new timeStamp is printed correctly. But in the main thread - when printing the timeStamp right after calling getLiveData – prints the former value. What's wrong?

```
    import Foundation

func getLiveData(){

let streamURL = URL(string: "https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/btc/metrics")
    
if let unwrappedURL = streamURL {
    var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
    
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("data.messari.io", forHTTPHeaderField: "host")
request.setValue("api/v1/assets/btc/metrics", forHTTPHeaderField: "path")
request.setValue("222222mysecretkey", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-messari-api-key")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
 
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        
            do {
                let myBCFeed = try JSONDecoder().decode(BCFeed.self, from: data) as BCFeed
                bcHour[currentHindex-1][0] = currentDateTime
                bcHour[currentHindex-1][1] = Int(round(myBCFeed.high1))
                bcHour[currentHindex-1][2] = Int(round(myBCFeed.low1))
                bcHour[currentHindex-1][3] = Int(round(myBCFeed.open1))
                metricsTimeStamp = myBCFeed.timestamp
                BCclose = myBCFeed.close1
                print(metricsTimeStamp) // prints correctly the new timeStamp
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        
    }).resume()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify the programming language as tag. Please delete it from the title as well.

Comment: Done and Thx for the advice